# How to correctly filter people by place of residence in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, grouping

I have a DB with more than 800 documents, like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5adf3c1544abaca147cdd399"),

"index" : 80,

"guid" : "ff1c8885-80fc-41de-a6e2-5a59ccd206e9",

"isActive" : true,

"balance" : "$2,249.41",

"picture" : "http://placehold.it/32x32",

"age" : 32,

"eyeColor" : "blue",

"name" : "Lenora Hayden",

"gender" : "female",

"company" : "FIREWAX",

"email" : "lenorahayden@firewax.com",

"phone" : "+1 (861) 457-2612",

"address" : "554 Bridge Street, Elbert, New Hampshire, 5327",

"about" : "Laborum id anim in ad officia duis est sunt ipsum cupidatat Lorem. Id non excepteur proident id aliqua ea ipsum enim. Sint velit enim proident dolore eiusmod aliqua velit elit id in deserunt. Sint ut magna et quis commodo aliquip consequat Lorem laboris sunt proident aute duis tempor.\r\n",

"registered" : "2014-03-27T09:37:45 -02:00",

"latitude" : -64.083596,

"longitude" : 13.025292,

"tags" : [
               "tempor",
               "velit",
               "do",
               "esse",
               "sunt",
               "enim",
               "eiusmod"
],

"friends" : [
                {
                        "id" : 0,
                        "name" : "Meadows Allen"
                },
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "name" : "Riggs Brown"
                },
                {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "name" : "Kris Fuller"
                }
        ],

"greeting" : "Hello, Lenora Hayden! You have 1 unread messages.",

"favoriteFruit" : "banana"
```

I need to find all the people who live in the state of New Hampshire, grouped by

```
db.usersdb.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$address"}}).pretty()
```

filters only at the address. How to find people living in a particular state and filter them?

Comment: [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) - There's a very detailed manual with very gentle tutorials. Read it. It's really worthwhile for you to actually do so.

Answer (score 0):

To filter on subset of collection, you should add a `$match` stage before filtering.

`$match` act as conditions to query your collection, the result will be processed in next stage

Read more about [$match here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html)